# Centos 6.5 Eclipse error when startup "Check Preferred PyDev Settings"

Tags: eclipse, pydev

### Heading

everytime I start my Eclipse, I got this Problem Occurred window pops out: " ‘Check Preferred PyDev Settings’ has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: "Check Preferred PyDev Settings".
INSTANCE"

And in the console:

```
$ eclipse 
CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode.forwardDeltaWith
CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding.<init>
CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates.instantiateTemplate
CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage.addBinding
CompilerOracle: exclude org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper.isValidSourceFile
CompilerOracle: exclude org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage.getDottedValidSourceFiles
### Excluding compile: static org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.PythonPathHelper::isValidSourceFile
### Excluding compile: static org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.PythonPathHelper::isValidSourceFile
### Excluding compile: static org.python.pydev.ui.filetypes.FileTypesPreferencesPage::getDottedValidSourceFiles
```

I can click OK to skip this, and I can still compile the python code in the eclipse, I just hate this annoying window, and want to figure out why.

Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.6.1

Linux 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 11:45:23 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just saw that you're using Eclipse 3.6. PyDev now requires Eclipse 3.8 onwards, so, to solve this issue you need to update Eclipse to a more recent version (see requirements on http://pydev.org/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to disable the annoy window: uncheck the Preferences -> PyDev -> "Check prefered Eclipse settings for PyDev on startup"

But I do not know why.

Comment: To stop the dialog appearing add the following to pluginCustomization.ini:

org.python.pydev/CHECK_PREFERRED_PYDEV_SETTINGS=false